# what regression to use if independent and dependent variables are categorical?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

see the title. I have 18 independent variables all on a scale of 1-5. My dependent variable in also on a scale of 1-5. Which regression model should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at [ordered logistic regression, also known as ordered logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit). We have an [ordered-logit](/questions/tagged/ordered-logit) tag. (Which assumes that your data are actually ordinal, not categorical, as suggested by your saying they are on a scale 1-5.)